# RabbitMQ implementation of the ACK like in MQTT

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

We have a specific problem with our RabbitMQ

We need to ensure that over many Queues with different topics there is a 1-1 and not 1-N messages. 
Just like in MQTT when one consumer acknowledges the push message it goes away.

The problem is that topics are an fan-out type.

Example:

one script publishes a message with routing key:

```
local.appNAme.clientName
```

And we have 2 ques with folowing rounting keys

```
que 1. local.*.clientName
que 2. local.#
```

They both get the Quqe as far i get it. And acknowledging one unlike in MQTT does not delete the other one.

Any idea how to implement the same behavior with routing wildcards in Rabbit?

ps. They are on the same server on the same Exchange.